# How to insert web form data to csv file using php

Tags: php, html, csv

I am trying to achieve data storage in csv file through web form, i tried  below codes which are saved in "form.html", "form1.php", "formTest.csv" and all three are in same directory.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="form1.php">
<table class="formatTblClass">
<tr>

</tr>
<tr>
<td width="68"><span>First Name</span></td>
<td width="215"><input class="<?=$aClass;?>" type="text" name="fn" id="fn" /></td>
<td width="62"><span>Last Name</span></td>
<td colspan="3"><input class="<?=$aClass;?>" name="ln" type="text" id="ln" size="50" /></td>
</tr>
<div align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
<input type="reset" name="Reset" id="button" value="Reset" />
</div>
</table>
</form>
```

Now form1.php script

```
<?php

$fn = $_POST['fn'];
$ln = $_POST['ln'];
if(empty($fn) || empty($ln))
  {//show the form
  $message = 'Fill in areas in red!';
  $aClass = 'errorClass';
}
$cvsData = $fn . "," . $ln . "\n";
$fp = fopen("formTest.csv","a");
if($fp){
  fwrite($fp,$cvsData); // Write information to the file
  fclose($fp); // Close the file
}
?>
```

Now formTest.csv file
[image]

If i run this in browser and again refreshed the csv file i am getting output like below picture

[image]

How to get proper user inputted output??
Thanks in advance

Comment: any errors passing??

Comment: In case of error (`if($fp){`) you open the file but do not close it, this might be the issue

Comment: Also, you append data to the file even if `$fn` and `$ln` are empty

Comment: @Voitcus i have closed } sir

Comment: If the content of the csv the same when you open it with a raw text editor instead of libre office?

Comment: only the header is displaying some thing like "fn","ln"

Comment: @AdityaK You do not close the **file** not bracket. You open the file with `fopen`, and then, if `$fp` is not true, you do not close the **file**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $fn = $_POST['fn'];
    $ln = $_POST['ln'];


    if(empty($fn) || empty($ln))
    {
        //show the form
        $message = 'Fill in areas in red!';
        $aClass = 'errorClass';
    }
    else
    {
        $fp = fopen('formTest.csv', 'w');

        $cvsData = $fn . "," . $ln . "\n";
        fputcsv($fp, $cvsData);//use fputscv()
        fclose($fp);
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding header to your code:

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
```

Comment: in php script or in html script??

Comment: its asking for download n if i download n open that file than its showing some junk value

Comment: try adding only one header i have updated the answer

Comment: if i include the header, than only its asking for download same script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
   <?php
    if(isset($_POST['fn']))
    {
    $csv=array();// take an array
    $fn = $_POST['fn'];
    $ln = $_POST['ln'];

    $csv[]=$fn;
    $csv[]=$ln;  //push the values in an array.

    if(empty($fn) || empty($ln))
      {//show the form
      $message = 'Fill in areas in red!';
      $aClass = 'errorClass';
    }

    $fp = fopen("formTest.csv","a");
    if($fp)
    {
      foreach ($csv as $val)
      {
         fputcsv($fp, $val); //write data in csv file.
      }
      fclose($fp); // Close the file
    }
}
    ?>
```